# Acer Aspire One usb linux cannot find CD / try again

Tags: installation, usb, acer

***UPDATE - I GIVE UP!! *****

Why is this so incredibly difficult to get to run off a variety of different / properly formatted USB sticks? Ubuntu looks great in the demo - but getting it is a joke. I'll drop off the Acer at Goodwill.

DETAILS:

Processor
Intel Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU N270 @ 1.60GHz

BIOS
Acer v0.3305

Video
Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS/GME, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller

Video
Intel Corporation Mobile 945GSE Express Integrated Graphics Controller

Network
Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller

Network
Atheros Communications Inc. AR242x / AR542x Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)

Storage
ATA SSDPAMM0008G1

Storage
Intel Corporation 82801GBM/GHM (ICH7-M Family) SATA Controller [IDE mode]

Comment: Forgot to add that it's a ZG5 model - a few years old now.

Comment: You can **edit** the *question* to add/correct any information that you think necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu **12.04 LTS** should be fine.

How much RAM?

---

Can you obtain/borrow a 'USB startup disk' created on Ubuntu 12.04 (or 12.10)? (eg. *Ask a friend.*)

Some of the alternate methods (on Windows, other Linux, earlier kernel, etc.) may have the boot device as a 'CD/DVD drive', so it will fail looking for a brand/model of CD/DVD matching your USB device. Alternatively, try burning a DVD (on Windows, other Linux, Mac).

Comment: That's a good idea, but I doubt any of my friends would have it. I will ask. I have tried with a memorex usb as well as an imation. I just want to get it working. One of those things that I've put in this much time, that I want to see through to the end. Anyone in Toronto or York Region willing to help a brother out? :) Thank you for your reply / suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that I'm not allowed to add comments (yet), here are my 2 cents: According to the system specs of the computer you have (ZG5, 512MB ram, 8GB SSD), I'd go with Lubuntu 12.10 because of the apparent low resource machine. I am using an emachines 355 (a renamed aspire one) and Ubuntu was a bit heavy for it so I switched to Lubuntu and it works like a charm.

Comment: Thank you user123492 - I am pulling down Lubuntu 12.04. I tried 12.10 - but Unetbootin doesn't go that high. I tried just mounting the iso from a usb stick, but ended up in the same place where it has trouble reading the CD-Drive - which makes me think it's just not finding the USB to use as a drive or disk. I tried a net install of ubuntu, got my wireless parameters and network all entered properly, then it just hangs at a purple screen with a command prompt and does nothing. I'm trying to resurrect this Linux based Acer Aspire (that will no longer update), but this is really a pain :)

Comment: Nope. Lubuntu 12.04 didn't work either. Text installer did the CD not found thing / retry - but then I took the USB out and said 'try again' - then it gave the option to check all drives, then put the USB back in and it found it - said it would use the ISO to install - then went back to the CD not found loop.